# How can I prove that this integrals are equal?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the following problem:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ be a sigma finite measure space and $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a mesurable function. Show that $$\int_\Omega fd\mu =\int_{[0,\infty)} \mu (\{x\in \Omega: f(x)\geq y\}) d\lambda (y)$$ I have just shown that $\{x\in \Omega: f(x)\geq y\}$ is in the product sigma algebra of $\Omega \times [0,\infty)$.

Now I really don't see how to show this, in the solution it seems to be a short one, but I somehow don't see how they procede. Could someone discuss it with me together, I don't want a full solution, it would be better if we can discuss it how to procede in such an exercise because I have really no idea.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This has been posted many times! Use https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: sorry what can I do on this side? how does it work?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor in the first answer of your link, how did he get $$\int_{(0,\infty)} \mu(\{f>t\}) \, dt=\int^\infty_0 \int _X \chi _{(\{f>t\})} \, d\mu \, dt$$ this equality

Comment: @Wave $\mu(A)=\int_A d\mu=\int_X\chi_A d\mu$.

Comment: ah okei thank you